# Multithreaded WinForm Calling a PowerShell Script .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, powershell, powershell-2.0

Will I run into any issues executing a single PowerShell script from a multithreaded WinForm app?  My main concern is related to the WinForm threads locking the PowerShell script.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= toProcess; i++)
{
    bWorker.ReportProgress(0, i.ToString());
    PowerShellProcs workPs = new PowerShellProcs();

    workPs.CusId = CustomerDataTable.Rows[i]["CustomerID"].ToString();

    ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(workPs.DoPs);
    Thread newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
    newThread.Name = CustomerDataTable.Rows[i]["CustomerID"].ToString();
    newThread.Start();

    if (toProcess == i)
    {
        resetEvent.Set();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    //threads.Add(newThread);
}

class PowerShellProcs
{
    public string CusId;
    public void DoPs()
    {
        String customerId = CusId;
        var scriptfile = @"c:\ProcessCustomer.ps1";         
        Process _Proc = new Process();
        _Proc.StartInfo = "Powershell.exe";
        _Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        _Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "'" + customerId + "' ";
        _Proc.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you like to start a process on another thread? `_Proc.Start()` is not blocking

Comment: Trying to run X updates at the same time.  Am I over complicating it?

Answer (score 0):

What if `toProcess` contains the value 1,000,000. then you're spawning 1m threads. The `_Proc.Start()` is not blocking, so your threads will be finished in no-time, but you will probably don't want to spawn 1m processes.

If you want to process them parallel, add the `process.WaitForExit();` (to make the executing process blocking) in the thread and put them on the `ThreadPool`. (The `ThreadPool` limits the concurrent threads (so also processes))

or

use the `Parallel.Foreach()` with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property.

Comment: At most, the process will have 5 threads spawned. Didn't think you could parallel process in .Net 3.5?

Comment: processes are always parallel. Didn't noticed the 3.5 requirement.

Comment: The spawned process could run for upwards of two hours. Not sure if this would lend better to a ThreadPool or not.  Once development is done, the code will be moved to a console app.

Comment: There is not directly a problem using the threadpool, as long that is the only thing the application does. Normally you shouldn't run long running tasks on the threadpool, because it will block other threadpool useritems. In this case there shouldn't be a problem.